# Spray json format for Unit type

Tags: scala, spray

I'm writing method with the following signature:

```
def foo[A: Marshaller, B: Marshaller](f: A => B) = {...}
```

The catch is that `A` could be `Unit`. It makes sense that there should be an already-existing json format for `Unit` that converts to and from the empty string, and it also makes sense that it should be trivial to implement such a format even if it doesn't exist. How can I define or import a json format for `Unit` like I do for case classes as follows:

```
implicit val myFormat = jsonFormat4(myCaseClassWithFourFields)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge no predefined json format for Unit exists.
But you can write your own json format:

```
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

implicit object UnitJsonFormat extends JsonFormat[Unit] {
  def write(u: Unit) = JsObject()
  def read(value: JsValue): Unit = value match {
      case JsObject(fields) if fields.isEmpty => Unit
  }
}
```

Using it:

```
scala> println("").toJson

res0: spray.json.JsValue = {}

scala> res0.convertTo[Unit]

scala>
```

Update: I'm not sure what you are expecting the json to look like for Unit, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question and later found out that `spray` provides `JsonFormats` for the most important `Scala Types`(e.g. `Int`, `Long`, `Float`, `Double`, `Byte`, `Short`, `BigDecimal`, `BigInt`, `Unit`, `Boolean`, `Char`, `String` and `Symbol`) in trait `BasicFormats`.

You can simply mixin [BasicFormats](https://github.com/spray/spray-json/blob/release/1.3.x/src/main/scala/spray/json/BasicFormats.scala) and it will work.